# Loop: Results to be updated via += if on the same date, otherwise write next line

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, dynamic

I have a function that produces some output like this

```
date         cashflow       count   etc
1/1/2000        40            3       ...
```

always a one-liner. This is created many times, with same or different dates. Now I would like a record of all results

```
date      cashflow         count    etc
1/1/2000     40              3      ...
```

so if a new result comes in with the same date / index, than it should add and update the field, i.e. via "+=", however if its a different date that does not already exists in the table, than it should just append and provide basis for further "updates", i.e.

new result

```
date      cashflow         count    etc
1/1/2000     -20              1      ...
```

then my table should show

```
date      cashflow         count    etc
1/1/2000     20              4      ...
```

however if a new results hits in with a date not yet existing in the table

```
date      cashflow         count    etc
2/1/2000     10              20     ...
```

then my table would look like

```
date      cashflow         count    etc
1/1/2000     20              4      ...
2/1/2000     10              20     ...
```

edit1: It seems my question did not come out clear: How would a program look like that could:

1) if index coincide: update values +=

2) if index not does not exist, extend the table by that line

edit2: How would I need to change the below code, if my date was set as an index?

edit3: Somehow this doesn't work within a loop: In a simple setup each of these one-liners are pd.DataFrames. However, in a loop they seem to be something else, such that I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

If I leave aout the `groupby`and use only `sum`:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

I think the loop is creating some kind of list of data frames; appending only works though.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.append` and then group by the column you want to use as an index.

Let's say that `total_df` is the table to which you want to add new rows,  `new_df` is the table containing those new rows and `date` is the column to be used as index. Then you can use:

```
total_df.append(new_df).groupby(by='date').sum()
```

Comment: thanks mcard. I am not there yet to test, but does it mean, if index is the same it sums up, if it's different it just appends?

Comment: Yes. Your question was pretty clear to me. First, the code appends one table to the other, and then it groups rows that have the same date together, summing up all other columns for each row that contains that date.

Comment: great, thank you very much! that's what i needed, since i cannot control how many rows (or dates with data) get spit out of the system.