# Merge pandas series with different index (align on one index)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, merge

I have results from different pandas series, which end up in a 1x1 series. Now I would like to merge them all to a 1xN row. Each of them could have different indices.

I could reset the index for each of them an create a new data frame. However, I wonder whether there is faster / easier method than that.

edit1: adding data and desired output sample

```
A
326    0.005077
dtype: float64

date
4300   2011-01-18 16:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

B
5    0.004077
dtype: float64
```

and I would like to have something like:

```
Index                    A            B
2011-01-18 16:00:00    0.005077     0.004077
```

the reason I want this: The program runs a loop and returns multiple of the above 1xN rows which I want to append to each other if the date is different, or summing up the values if the date (index) is identical (which can be done as shown here: [Loop: Results to be updated via += if on the same date, otherwise write next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681606/loop-results-to-be-updated-via-if-on-the-same-date-otherwise-write-next-lin/49682298?noredirect=1#comment86383372_49682298)

edit2: Apologies I had some exceptions in my code where I had to set certain series object = 0. Is there any way to include that in your one liner below or do I need to make pd.series out of my zeros?

Comment: Can you add data sample and expected output?

Comment: Do you think another `C` Series with `0` ? Then `df = pd.DataFrame([np.concatenate([A, B, C])], columns=['A','B', 'C'], index=date) should working nice
print (df)`

Comment: sorry for being unclear. it's a scalar, i.e. C = 0, so not a series yet. Imagine, that the series C = X / Y, and Y could be zero, so I added:
If Y == 0: C = 0, else: C = X / Y. In the else statement C is a pd.series whereas if the if statement is true, C is a scalar

Comment: Answer was edited.

Comment: hmmm, so `C` should be sometimes `one value` `Series` and sometimes scalar?

Comment: yes, that's the problem: sometimes C is one value series and sometimes a scalar. I thought of C = [0], would that work? edit: unfortunately too naive from me.

Comment: I think need `if-else` like `C = C if isinstance(C, pd.Series) else [C]`, it working if `C = 0` and also `C = pd.Series([0])`

Comment: Or more specific `C = C if isinstance(C, pd.Series) else pd.Series([C])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need:

```
A = pd.Series([0.005077], index=[326])
date = pd.Series(['2011-01-18 16:00:00'], index=[4300])
B = pd.Series([ 0.004077], index=[5])

df = pd.DataFrame([np.concatenate([A, B])], columns=['A','B'], index=date)
print (df)
                            A         B
2011-01-18 16:00:00  0.005077  0.004077
```

EDIT:

for scalar is necessary create one item list:

```
A = pd.Series([0.005077], index=[326])
date = pd.Series(['2011-01-18 16:00:00'], index=[4300])
B = pd.Series([ 0.004077], index=[5])
C = 0

df = pd.DataFrame([np.concatenate([A, B, [C] ])], columns=['A','B','C'], index=date)
print (df)
                            A         B    C
2011-01-18 16:00:00  0.005077  0.004077  0.0
```

Comment: Resulting df is Nx1. Just a suggestion.

Comment: thanks, jezrael and Rao Sahab. would that be in my case:
df = pd.concat([A, B]).to_frame([date]).T?

Comment: @jezrael Can you please add set index to fit his requirement

Comment: @eternity1 - For you too!